# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_utils'

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, python-3.10, huggingface

I'm unable to use HuggingFace (transformers) pretrained model, I'm trying to run the .frompretrained() function, specifically:

```
from transformers import BertModel, AutoModel
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

and I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_utils'
```

If it helps, I get this when I run it:

```
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ in <module>:2                                                                                    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   1 from transformers import BertModel, AutoModel                                                │
│ ❱ 2 model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')                                       │
│   3                                                                                              │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/gpt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py:2600  │
│ in from_pretrained                                                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│   2597 │   │   if from_pt:                                                                       │
│   2598 │   │   │   if not is_sharded and state_dict is None:                                     │
│   2599 │   │   │   │   # Time to load the checkpoint                                             │
│ ❱ 2600 │   │   │   │   state_dict = load_state_dict(resolved_archive_file)                       │
│   2601 │   │   │                                                                                 │
│   2602 │   │   │   # set dtype to instantiate the model under:                                   │
│   2603 │   │   │   # 1. If torch_dtype is not None, we use that dtype                            │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/gpt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py:446   │
│ in load_state_dict                                                                               │
│                                                                                                  │
│    443 │   """                                                                                   │
│    444 │   if checkpoint_file.endswith(".safetensors") and is_safetensors_available():           │
│    445 │   │   # Check format of the archive                                                     │
│ ❱  446 │   │   with safe_open(checkpoint_file, framework="pt") as f:                             │
│    447 │   │   │   metadata = f.metadata()                                                       │
│    448 │   │   if metadata.get("format") not in ["pt", "tf", "flax"]:                            │
│    449 │   │   │   raise OSError(                                                                │
│                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/gpt_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/storage.py:779 in from_file    │
│                                                                                                  │
│   776 │   │   untyped_storage: UntypedStorage = UntypedStorage.from_file(                        │
│   777 │   │   │   filename,                                                                      │
│   778 │   │   │   shared,                                                                        │
│ ❱ 779 │   │   │   size * torch._utils._element_size(cls.dtype))                                  │
│   780 │   │   storage = cls(wrap_storage=untyped_storage)                                        │
│   781 │   │   return storage                                                                     │
│   782
```

I've tried other models using the same from_pretrained() function and a similar error happens.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you replicate my versions as it works for me

```
>>> import torch
>>> torch.__version__
'2.0.1+cpu'
>>> import torchvision
>>> torchvision.__version__
'0.15.2+cpu'
>>> torch._utils
<module 'torch._utils' from 'C:\'
```

Answer (score 0):

`torch._utils` has existed since [PyTorch version 0.1.2](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/v0.1.2/torch), so either your installation is broken, or PyTorch's `torch` module is shadowed by a second module named `torch` in your code base or PYTHONPATH (i.e. a `torch.py` or a directory named `torch` containing an `__init__.py`). Probably the latter.